# How to parse nullable DateTime object in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

```
command.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
     EndDate == null ? 
        (DateTime?)null : 
        DateTime.Parse(EndDate.ToShortDateString() + " " + EndTime);
```

EndDate is of type DateTime? and EndTime is just a string containing time. But it is giving me error while parsing because EndDate is a nullable DateTime. How can I parse this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to get the value using below

```
DateTime.Parse(EndDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToShortDateString() + " " + EndTime);
```

Answer (score 5):

As EndDate is a nullable so you can parse it like that.

```
DateTime.Parse(EndDate.Value.ToShortDateString() + " " + EndTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally use `default(DateTime?)` and you'll also need to cast to a nullable DateTime object:

```
return EndDate.HasValue ? DateTime.Parse(EndDate.Value.ToShortDateString() + " " + EndTime) as DateTime? : default(DateTime?)
```

Comment: Still error:
Error 1 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'ToShortDateString' and no extension method 'ToShortDateString' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Waheed Ahmed\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Events\Events\Repositories\EventsRepository.cs 175 153 Events

Answer (score 0):

You need to use: EndDate.HasValue.ToShortDateString():

Converting your code:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
EndDate.HasValue == false ? 
(DateTime?)null : 
DateTime.Parse(EndDate.HasValue.ToShortDateString() + " " + EndTime);
```

You could also write the following:

```
        var endDateParameter = endDate.HasValue ?
        new SqlParameter("EndDate", DateTime.Parse(EndDate.HasValue.ToShortDateString() + " " + EndTime)) :
        new SqlParameter("EndDate", typeof(System.DateTime));
```

Cheers,
Noah